# Is there any REST API or call to Azure which I can use to verify if my subscription id, client id, client secret and tenant id are valid?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, rest, azure-authentication, service-principal

I have a problem where user can add their **azure client id, client secret, tenant id and subscription id** and we have to **validate** using some way if the entries given by user are **correct or not.**

Is there any way I can verify if the details of client id, client secret, tenant id, subscription id are correct in Azure?

Answer (score 1):

There is no official document about verify the ids.

You could try to request Token by Postman, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). If you could get successful response, the ids are valid.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=qWgdYAmab0YSkuL1qKv5bPX
&grant_type=client_credentials
```